# Ubuntu 14.01.1 LTS (apt-get update not woking)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I need your help.

```
$ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64     

$ vagrant up
```

everything is fine. But i can't "

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I always get

```
W: Failed to fetch

Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com
```

What happened? My internet connection is working fine or is there something wrong with Ubuntu server?

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Ok i'll head there and ask them :D

Comment: For me simply `vagrant reload` worked and I could see the domain resolved correctly

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your base box doesnt have DNS set up correctly. Try adding openDNS to your /etc/resolv.conf.

Adding the following to your vagrantfile (within the configuration part) should do the trick

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  ...

  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sudo echo nameserver 208.67.222.222 > /etc/resolv.conf"

  ...

end
```

Once added, just run 'vagrant reload --provision' then ssh in and try again

Comment: There's an issue with the quotes in your example, but this worked for me:

config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sudo echo 'nameserver 208.67.222.222' > /etc/resolv.conf"

Answer (score -1):

well,I have the same problem.
I edited the /etc/resolv.conf file , write this :
nameserver 208.67.222.222
and then it worked!